# R: Update row if any previous row contains a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a set of data taken from an RFID reader which records when individual birds visit a nest. However, errors with the boards meant they often would stop scanning for day, and so I don't know if the bird visited the nest or not. The dataset contains a record of both the time of the most recent detection, and the date and time of the previous detection. I'd like to update this 'previous visit' column with 'unknown' when the board was off for any day prior to the last known visit.

My minimal dataset is below:

```
date <- seq.POSIXt(ISOdate(2018, 7, 6), ISOdate(2018,7,16), by = "day")
status <- c("ON","ON","OFF","ON","ON", "ON", "ON", "ON", "ON","ON", "ON")
firstdet <- c("2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST", NA, NA , NA ,               
               NA  , "2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST","2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST", "2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST",
             "2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST" ,"2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST" ,"2018-07-16 23:57:00 BST")
prevVisit <- c(NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA ,"2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST", "2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST",
               "2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST", "2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST",
              "2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST" ,"2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST")

mydf <- data.frame(cbind(as.character(date), status, firstdet, prevVisit))
colnames(mydf)[1] <- "date"
```

Which looks like this:

```
            date       status                firstdet               prevVisit
1  2018-07-06 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST                    <NA>
2  2018-07-07 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
3  2018-07-08 12:00:00    OFF                    <NA>                    <NA>
4  2018-07-09 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
5  2018-07-10 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
6  2018-07-11 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST 2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST
7  2018-07-12 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST
8  2018-07-13 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST
9  2018-07-14 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST
10 2018-07-15 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST 2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST
11 2018-07-16 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-16 23:57:00 BST 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST
```

*N.B. The birds visit at night between 22:00 and 03:00 so the date column refers to the day the night started; this is why the firstdet column date doesn't always match the date.*

I would like the 'prevVisit' column to update with 'unknown' whenever any of the rows between the current detection and the last known one contain status 'OFF' - as I don't know for certain when the bird last visited. For example:

```
              date     status                firstdet               prevVisit
1  2018-07-06 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST                    <NA>
2  2018-07-07 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
3  2018-07-08 12:00:00    OFF                    <NA>                    <NA>
4  2018-07-09 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
5  2018-07-10 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>
6  2018-07-11 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST UNKNOWN
7  2018-07-12 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST
8  2018-07-13 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST
9  2018-07-14 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST
10 2018-07-15 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST 2018-07-14 23:46:47 BST
11 2018-07-16 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-16 23:57:00 BST 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST
```

I have come across lots of questions which ask how to change row values based on previous rows, however none of these seem to be conditioned on a variable range of previous rows, so they haven't solved my issue.

The closest I've gotten is an ifelse statement which I hoped would search for 'OFF' in the preceding rows of the status column - but this doesn't work:

```
mydf$prevVisit <- ifelse("OFF" %in% mydf$status[which(mydf$date > mydf$prevVisit & mydf$date < mydf$firstdet)], "unknown", mydf$prevVisit)
```

Comment: If your columns are truly `POSIXct` as they appear to be, you either (a) cannot introduce `"UNKNOWN"` in as a string, or (b) all of the other dates in that column will be converted to `character` strings, in which case date logic/math no longer apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an elegant/vectorizable way to go about this, and `ifelse` is certainly not going to do what you want. Here's a quick hack that might work for you.

I modified your data slightly to give another test (that I don't falsely assign "unknown" in a gap):

```
x <- read.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, text="
               date status                firstdet               prevVisit
2018-07-06_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-07_03:34:58_BST                      NA
2018-07-07_12:00:00     ON                      NA                      NA
2018-07-08_12:00:00    OFF                      NA                      NA
2018-07-09_12:00:00     ON                      NA                      NA
2018-07-10_12:00:00     ON                      NA                      NA
2018-07-11_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-12_01:30:37_BST 2018-07-07_03:34:58_BST
2018-07-12_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-13_03:15:55_BST 2018-07-12_01:30:37_BST
2018-07-13_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14_00:01:39_BST 2018-07-13_03:15:55_BST
2018-07-14_12:00:00     ON                      NA 2018-07-14_00:01:39_BST
2018-07-15_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-15_23:28:16_BST 2018-07-14_00:01:39_BST
2018-07-16_12:00:00     ON 2018-07-16_23:57:00_BST 2018-07-15_23:28:16_BST")
x[] <- lapply(x, function(a) gsub("_", " ", a))

x$unknown <- c(FALSE, sapply(seq_len(nrow(x))[-1], function(i) {
  prev <- tail(which(!is.na(x$firstdet[seq_len(i-1)])), n = 1)
  !is.na(x$firstdet[i]) && (!length(prev) || any(x$status[prev:i] == "OFF"))
}))

x$prevVisit <- ifelse(is.na(x$firstdet) | x$unknown, NA, lag(zoo::na.locf(x$firstdet)))
x
#                   date status                firstdet               prevVisit unknown
# 1  2018-07-06 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-07 03:34:58 BST                    <NA>   FALSE
# 2  2018-07-07 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>   FALSE
# 3  2018-07-08 12:00:00    OFF                    <NA>                    <NA>   FALSE
# 4  2018-07-09 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>   FALSE
# 5  2018-07-10 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>   FALSE
# 6  2018-07-11 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST                    <NA>    TRUE
# 7  2018-07-12 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST 2018-07-12 01:30:37 BST   FALSE
# 8  2018-07-13 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST 2018-07-13 03:15:55 BST   FALSE
# 9  2018-07-14 12:00:00     ON                    <NA>                    <NA>   FALSE
# 10 2018-07-15 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST 2018-07-14 00:01:39 BST   FALSE
# 11 2018-07-16 12:00:00     ON 2018-07-16 23:57:00 BST 2018-07-15 23:28:16 BST   FALSE
```

(The modified data shows that row 10 shows row 8's `firstdet` despite the gap in row 9.)

I am assuming you intend to make these real dates at one point, so I kept it in a separate column (because you cannot have `"UNKNOWN"` in a `POSIXt` column). If you really want it in there, you can else do

```
x$prevVisit <- ifelse(x$unknown, "UNKNOWN", x$prevVisit)
```